# fill text fetched from database into text fiels on selection of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am fetching data from database , for each of row data fetched I am creating a radio button against the row. The details of a land-sites are fetched here.

I have a form for booking these land sites, which takes land-site details and name and email of user.

So when a user selects a radio button, the details of land-site should be automatically filled in the form, How to achieve this.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php 
        $phase=$_GET["q"];
        $sql ="select id, phase,size, facing, sply, status from plot where status='avail'       and phase='$phase'";
        $ret=mysql_query($sql, $connect);

        echo "<form>";

    echo"<div style='overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;float:left;' ><table border=1 >
    <tr>
    <td>select </td><td>phase</td> <td>site no.</td> <td>plot-size</td> <td>face</td> <td>sply</td> <td>status</td>
    </tr>" ;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ret, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

        echo "<tr>".
            "<td><input type='radio' name='book' value='book' onClick=\"whichForm('send_to_one');\" /></td>".
            "<td>{$row['phase']}  </td>".
             "<td>{$row['id']} </td>".
             "<td> {$row['size']} </td>".
             "<td> {$row['facing']} </td>".
             "<td>{$row['sply']} </td> ".
             "<td>{$row['status']} </td> ".
             "</tr>";        
    } 
    echo "</table></div>";

    mysql_close($connect);

    ?>

    <div id="send_to_one" style="float:right;padding:30px">

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mobile:</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Email :</td> <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phase : </td> <td><select name="phase" id="phase">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Site :</td> <td> <input type="text" name="site" value="" id="site" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!--
    <tr><td><span id="status"></span></td></tr>
    -->
    <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="status" value="blocked" class="radioBtn"  onclick="advance.disabled=true" /> block</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="status" value="booked"  class="radioBtn"  onclick="advance.disabled=false" /> book </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Advance paid </td> <td><input type="text" name="advance" value="" id="textField" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td> <td> <input type="reset" value="clear all" /> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo "</form>"; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- div ends here -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Some code that you have tried might help here!

Comment: Can you please show us a little bit of code? In this way we may help you a little bit more :]

Comment: i have added the code now